# How to set event listeners in Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I would like to ask on how you can set your own event listener in your Cordova plugin.

I have this `Share dialog` for my Android and I wanted to have my Javascript to set a listener for `onShareDialogDismiss` or `onShareDialogLaunched`

What would likely to happen in Javascript would look like this.

```
// Set a listener for dialog dismiss
document.addEventListener('onShareDialogDismiss', listenerCallback, false);

// Set a listener for dialog launch
document.addEventListener('onShareDialogLaunch', launchCallback, false);
```

I have this code from Titanium, but it's using `TiViewProxy` class, would likely to know how you could do an alternative for `fireEvent()` in pure Android implementation

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly have you already read [Cordova plugin development documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html)?

Then you can see how a plugin like this [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) is done :

Check for example the [JS interface code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/www/network.js) in which there are these code lines to raise a Document event:

```
cordova.fireDocumentEvent("offline");
```

or

```
cordova.fireDocumentEvent("online");
```

Reading inside **cordova.js** there is a minimal documentation for this API:

```
/**
 * Method to fire event from native code
 * bNoDetach is required for events which cause an exception which needs to be caught in native code
 */
fireDocumentEvent: function(type, data, bNoDetach)
```

Another API available is `fireWindowEvent: function(type, data)`, but you can find out other APIs reading directly inside cordova.js.

Comment: The network info plugin features a rather cumbersome implementation of "events" by using a timer that runs every half second to check if the status has changed. There should be a smarter way to trigger events without using Javascript timers, in fact this is a "cheating" method, not a real event-trigger mechanism.

Comment: I agree @andreszs. Something like a BroadcastReceiver (with filter on ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) should have been used.